# How to pass a data to another fragment and retrieve it as well

Tags: java, android

The data was null when I retrieve it but in my firebase there is nothing problem

I already pass the data from profile users fragment to the job users fragment but the error keep saying that data was null because I would like to create a page when the profile preference
(IT or NON-IT) have a same value with job preference(dataPre) it will display at the page. In my home users fragment, I already display all jobs that have been stored in firebase and I want to implement same method in job users fragment but the different is I want this page specified the jobs based on the profile preference.

JobUsersFragment.java

```
package com.example.jobrecruitment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JobUsersFragment extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ValueEventListener eventListener;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<DataClass> dataList;
    private UserAdapter adapter;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private String userPreference;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_users, container, false);

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        searchView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchView.clearFocus();

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Retrieve the user's profile preference
        userPreference = retrieveUserProfilePreference();

        Log.d("JobUsersFragment", "User Profile Preference: " + userPreference);

        adapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity(), dataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Use the user's profile preference in the Firebase Database query
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Android Tutorials");
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("dataPre").equalTo(userPreference);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


        eventListener = query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                dataList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DataClass dataClass = itemSnapshot.getValue(DataClass.class);
                    dataClass.setKey(itemSnapshot.getKey());

                    Log.d("JobUsersFragment", "DataClass dataPre: " + dataClass.getDataPre() + ", User Preference: " + userPreference);

                    // Only add items to the list if their dataPre matches the user's preference
                    if (dataClass.getDataPre().equals(userPreference)) {
                        dataList.add(dataClass);
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("JobUsersFragment", "Database Error: " + error.getMessage());
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                searchList(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Retrieve data passed from ProfileUsersFragment
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            handleData(args);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private String retrieveUserProfilePreference() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("preference")) {
            String preference = args.getString("preference", "");
            Log.d("JobUsersFragment", "Retrieved user preference from arguments: " + preference);
            // Check if the preference is either "IT" or "NON-IT", default to "NON-IT" otherwise
            return "IT".equals(preference) ? "IT" : "NON-IT";
        } else {
            Log.d("JobUsersFragment", "No user preference found in arguments. Defaulting to NON-IT.");
            return "NON-IT";
        }
    }


    private void searchList(String text) {
        ArrayList<DataClass> searchList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataClass dataClass : dataList) {
            if (dataClass.getDataTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                searchList.add(dataClass);
            }
        }
        adapter.searchDataList(searchList);
    }

    // Method to handle data received from ProfileUsersFragment
    public void handleData(Bundle bundle) {
        String username = bundle.getString("username", "");
        String name = bundle.getString("name", "");
        String email = bundle.getString("email", "");
        String password = bundle.getString("password", "");
        String preference = bundle.getString("preference", "");
        String image = bundle.getString("image", "");

        Log.d("JobUsersFragment", "Received data from ProfileUsersFragment: " + username + ", " + name + ", " + email + ", " + password + ", " + preference + ", " + image);

        // Now you can use the received data as needed in your fragment
    }
}
```

ProfileUsersFragment.java

```
package com.example.jobrecruitment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ProfileUsersFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView profileName, profileEmail, profileUsername, profilePassword, profilePreference;
    private Button editProfile;
    private ImageView profileImage;
    private String imageUrl; // Ensure to declare imageUrl at the class level


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_users, container, false);

        profileName = view.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        profileEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profileUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        profilePassword = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        profilePreference = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePreference);
        profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        editProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.editButton);

        showAllUserData();

        editProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                passUserData();
            }
        });

        // Call passData as needed, for example, in onCreateView or another appropriate place
        passData();

        return view;
    }

    public void showAllUserData() {
        Intent intent = requireActivity().getIntent();
        String usernameUser = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query userQuery = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(usernameUser);

        userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String nameUser = userSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailUser = userSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        String passwordUser = userSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                        String preference = userSnapshot.child("preference").getValue(String.class);
                        imageUrl = userSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class); // Update class-level variable

                        profileName.setText(nameUser);
                        profileEmail.setText(emailUser);
                        profileUsername.setText(usernameUser);
                        profilePassword.setText(passwordUser);
                        profilePreference.setText(preference);

                        if (imageUrl != null) {
                            Glide.with(requireContext()).load(imageUrl).into(profileImage);
                        } else {
                            Glide.with(requireContext()).load(R.drawable.uploadimg).into(profileImage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Handle onCancelled
            }
        });
    }

    public void passUserData() {
        String userUsername = profileUsername.getText().toString().trim();

        Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), EditProfile.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", userUsername);
        intent.putExtra("name", profileName.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("email", profileEmail.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("password", profilePassword.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("preference", profilePreference.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("image", imageUrl);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Add passData method to pass data to JobUsersFragment
    public void passData() {
        String userUsername = profileUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String userPreference = profilePreference.getText().toString().trim();

        Log.d("PassData", "passData() called with username: " + userUsername + ", preference: " + userPreference);


        JobUsersFragment jobUsersFragment = (JobUsersFragment) requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("JobUsersFragment");


        if (jobUsersFragment != null && jobUsersFragment.isAdded()) {
            // Create a Bundle and set the data
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("username", userUsername);
            bundle.putString("name", profileName.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("email", profileEmail.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("password", profilePassword.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("preference", userPreference);
            bundle.putString("image", imageUrl);

            // Call a method in JobUsersFragment to handle the data
            jobUsersFragment.handleData(bundle);
        } else {

            Log.d("PassData", "JobUsersFragment is not added to the fragment manager.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data using Interface from ProfileUsersFragment to JobUsersFragment.

```
public interface PassData {

void onPassData(String name, String email ,String password ,String 
preference ,String image);
}
```

Then ProfileUsersFragment onAttach() to give context

> passData = (PassData) context;

then pass Data Through Interface

```
 public void passData() {
    String userUsername = profileUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    String userPreference = profilePreference.getText().toString().trim();
    passData.onPassData("","","","","");
  
    
 }
```

Retrive Data from JobUsersFragment , First of all implements PassData and override onPassData() Method. and get Value

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order to fix your problem:

In the passData method of ProfileUsersFragment, you are creating a Bundle and adding data to it. Ensure that the keys used to retrieve data in JobUsersFragment match the keys used to put data in the Bundle. In both fragments, you are using the same keys, so that seems correct.

In JobUsersFragment, you are trying to retrieve the data from the arguments using the same keys used in ProfileUsersFragment. The keys seem to match, but ensure that the handleData method is being called after the fragment is created and attached.

In the passData method of ProfileUsersFragment, you are checking if the JobUsersFragment is added using isAdded(). This checks if the fragment is currently added to the activity, but you should also ensure that the JobUsersFragment is created before trying to pass data to it. Consider checking if the fragment is not null and has been instantiated.